# Incrementally increasing speed of animation by clicks NSTimer, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm new to coding and Swift so pardon me if it's a noob question. I'm trying to accelerate the speed of my animation with every click of a button. I tried to do a new variable and dividing it in my button actions but doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for your time!

```
var animationSpeed:Double = 0.4
timerF = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
             animationSpeed, target: self,  
             selector: "doanimation", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Can we see some more code? What are you trying to get your app to do with this animation? You may not need NSTimer to do this.

Comment: Hey Beau, thanks for checking! It was indeed a noob mistake. That's what you get for trying to learn code in 2 days.... I was trying to get the speed of animation to increase by every click. It works now with this code: animationSpeed = (animationSpeed - 0.1)  I forgot the () the last time. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your issue?